# Can't access CloudKit for strange error: Internal Error (1/2005)

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud, cloudkit

My project worked fine with XCode 7 on iOS 9. But after building with XCode 8 on iOS 10, CloudKit gave this error:

```
[LogFacilityCK] Couldn't get connection for container <private>, failing operation. NSError: Internal Error (1/2005).
```

When I call this function below:

```
[[CKContainer defaultContainer] accountStatusWithCompletionHandler:^(CKAccountStatus accountStatus, NSError *error) {}];
```

Has someone met this problem before? Thank you for your help!

ApplicationPermissionStatus is CKApplicationPermissionStatusCouldNotComplete.
Later, I tested on iOS10.0.1 and iOS10.0.0, everything worked fine except iOS10.0.2. It's so weird. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Reboot your iOS device. After upgrading one of my test iPhones to iOS 10.1 CKContainer returned a NSError with CKApplicationPermissionStatusCouldNotComplete in the completionBlock of the function requestApplicationPermission:completionHandler: and statusForApplicationPermission:completionHandler: too. The iCloud user was authenticated on that device but the Settings app do not provide any information about the iCloud user (storage e.g.). After rebooting the device all information are provided and the function calls return no errors.

Comment: Rebooted several times but still not working. I upgrated my iphone to iOS 10.1 and everything worked fine. I still think maybe this is a bug of iOS 10.0.2 (especially the photo iCloud bug mentioned in 10.1 bug fixing log) Thanks anyway~